# MS Access Permissions

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to make design changes to the forms in a MS Access MDB file but do not have permissions.  I am logged in as the admin user of the file but it only has read/open permission and there are no other users with permissions other than read/open.  When I try to add permissions to any users it says I do not have permissions to do that.

Is there any way around this?  How can there be no users with full permissions to the DB?

Comment: Are you talking about an MDB database which has ULS (user level security) applied?

Comment: Yes, it was not something I set up however.  I am going to Tools --> Security to view the permissions.  The file itself has Windows security applied but as administrator I full access to that.

Comment: Typically in an MDB secured with ULS, the Admin security account is removed from the administrators group and another user is given administrator membership/permissions.  Since it appears you're connecting as the Admin *user*, that makes me wonder whether you're  connecting with the actual workgroup information file which was used to secure the db.  Can you check with whoever set it up originally?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a very old DB app and was set up by someone who hasn't worked here in many years.  That being said I could look in some places for the workgroup information file but I am not sure what it would look like or how to use it.  Does it have an extension other than .mdb?

Comment: The file extension I see most often is *.mdw*, but that is not an absolute requirement.  How are you opening the db now?  Does your method reference *any* additional file other than the main application MDB file?

Comment: We put the MDB file on user's computers and they simply open it, no passwords.  It does link to a SQL DB through an ODBC connection that we set up on each computer but those permissions shouldn't affect changing the front end MDB forms, should it?  Regardless I have full access to the SQL DB as well.

Comment: You're right ... SQL Server permissions are separate from Access security permissions.  But you still need Access security rights to modify form design.  I don't see how you can do that without using the proper workgroup information file and logging in with a privileged Access security account defined in that workgroup file.

Comment: Is it possible to create a new MDB without ULS and just copy all of the objects form the old one to it?  There are not than many forms and linked tables.

Comment: Yes, you can try.  But the Admin user must have "read design" privilege for those objects you want to copy.  Without that privilege, you may be SOL.

Comment: You are right, I can't copy those objects either, it looks like creating a new front end is the only option.  Thanks for the information.